# Disable fields based on user input in Slack forms

Tags: slack

I'm working on a Slack form to check firewall rules. The user trigger a form using the /command. The form is presented to put source, destination, dropdown to select protocol (TCP/DPP/ICPM) the port number. But when you select the ICMP there is no port number. But I cannot pass the port number field because Slack to the user input checks.

Is there a way to disable the port field if the user select the ICMP field? Does Slack support this feature? Thank you very much in advance!!!

Below is part of the code snippet.

@app.command("/firewall_check")
def open_modal(ack, body,client, logger):
# Acknowledge the command request
ack()
# Call views_open with the built-in client
client.views_open(
# Pass a valid trigger_id within 3 seconds of receiving it
trigger_id=body["trigger_id"],
# View payload
view={
"title": {
"type": "plain_text",
"text": "Firewall rules check"
},
"submit": {
"type": "plain_text",
"text": "Submit"
},
"type": "modal",
"callback_id": "view_7",
"close": {
"type": "plain_text",
"text": "Cancel"
},
"blocks": [
{
"type": "section",
"text": {
"type": "plain_text",
"text": "Use the following form to check firewall rules"
}
},
{
"type": "divider"
},
{
"type": "input",
"block_id": "SrcIP_block_input",
"element": {
"type": "plain_text_input",
"action_id": "sourceIP"
},
"label": {
"type": "plain_text",
"text": "Source IP"
},
},
{
"type": "input",
"block_id": "DestIP_block_input",
"element": {
"type": "plain_text_input",
"action_id": "DestIP_action_input"
},
"label": {
"type": "plain_text",
"text": "Destination IP:"
},
},
{
"type": "input",
"block_id": "Port_block_input",
"element": {
"type": "plain_text_input",
"action_id": "Port_action_input",
},
"label": {
"type": "plain_text",
"text": "TCP port number"
}
},
{
"type": "section",
"block_id": "Protocol_block_input",
"text": {
"type": "mrkdwn",
"text": "*Protocol (TCP / UDP)*"
},
"accessory": {
"type": "multi_static_select",

```
                    "placeholder": {
                        "type": "plain_text",

                        "text": "Select options",
                        "emoji": True
                    },
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "text": {
                                "type": "plain_text",

                                "text": "TCP",
                                "emoji": True
                            },
                            "value": "tcp"
                        },
                        {
                            "text": {
                                "type": "plain_text",

                                "text": "UDP",
                                "emoji": True
                            },
                            "value": "udp"
                        },
                        {
                            "text": {
                                "type": "plain_text",

                                "text": "ICMP (ping)",
                                "emoji": True
                            },
                            "value": "icmp"
                        },
                    ],
                    "action_id": "Protocol_action_input"
                },
            }
        ]
    }
)
```